# How to convert [object Map] to displayable text in handlebars

Tags: javascript, express-handlebars

I have a json object called users and passed by the same name to my handlebars file.
When I call it with:

{{users}}

It displays as [object Map] I want to use the json data to display certain information by looping through it, but when I try that noting shows.

The loop I use is:

```
{{#each users}} {{this}} {{/each}}
```

Comment: JSON is a format; what you have is a JavaScript Object. Anyway, please add the handlebars loop code you've tried and show how the users Objects looks inside.

Comment: I also found this: http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/N2b5M/1/

Comment: The loop I use is:

Comment: {{#each users}} {{this}} {{/each}}

Comment: Assuming `users` is an array of strings, that should work fine. But we cannot help you like this.